# Correct positioning of views in SwiftUI chartsBackground

Tags: swiftui, charts

With the new **Charts** for SwiftUI that Apple released in July 2022, we can now make charts with extraordinary ease. There is a view modifier in Charts, **chartBackground**, where we can use SwiftUI views as a background to the chart. I have tried to use the chartBackground with mixed results, because I do not understand how to position the views correctly.

The codebase I have here is a simplified version of the chart view in my app, to illustrate the problem I have.

The chart is a line chart, with an array of **EnergyPriceData**:

```swift
struct EnergyPriceData: Identifiable {
    var id: String { UUID().uuidString }
    let date: Date
    let cent: Double
}
```

The cents are plotted on the y-axis, with dates on the x-axis.

The background for the chart is in the **chartBackground** modifier:

```swift
.chartBackground { proxy in
    GeometryReader { geo in
        if let startDate = startDate, let endDate = endDate, let startPositionX = proxy.position(forX: startDate), let endPositionX = proxy.position(forX: endDate) {
            let height = geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].height
            let width = geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].width
            let _ = print("startDate:", startDate, "endDate:", endDate, "startPositionX:", startPositionX, "xdiff:", endPositionX - startPositionX, "width:", width)
            Rectangle()
                .fill(Color.green.opacity(0.06))
                .position(x: 208, y: height / 2)
                .frame(width: endPositionX - startPositionX, height: height)
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the app in the simulator, the following is printed out by the print statement, so I get an idea what the coordinates and positions are:

**startDate**: 2022-10-15 18:00:19 +0000 **endDate**: 2022-10-16 03:00:19 +0000 **startPositionX**: 56.46153846153847 **xdiff**: 254.0769230769231 **width**: 367.0

I want to have a color of green with an opacity of 0.06 between the two green vertical lines, and found out by experimenting, that a position value for x of **208** would give me that. The width of the green area is the **endPositionX** - **startPositionX**. By googling around, the sparse information I could fine how to calculate the startPositionX is `let startPositionX = proxy.position(forX: startDate)`. But that can't be true, because the printout above gives a much smaller value, 56.46 than the value 208. And I am not able to find out how to get the correct value of startPositionX from the GeometryReader.

And when I swipe on the chart, the green area is moving outside the start and stop vertical green lines.

This short video illustrates the problem: [SwiftUI Chart swiping](https://youtube.com/shorts/74cKv-itH8k?feature=share)

Below is the complete code of the chart view, if you want to see how the chart looks like, you can just replace the ContentView.swift file of a new SwiftUI project with the following:

```swift
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct ContentView: View {
    let prices: [Double] = [268.613, 264.863, 242.250, 240.813, 237.350, 200.050, 225.050, 211.063, 212.838, 225.588, 227.388, 244.238, 271.588, 314.875]
    let startDate: Date
    let endDate: Date
    var dates: [Date] = []
    var data: [EnergyPriceData] = []
    @State var selectedDate: Date?
    @State var selectedCent: Double?
    var hourMinuteFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm"
        formatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return formatter
    }
    var hourFormatter: DateFormatter {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH"
        formatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        formatter.timeZone = TimeZone.current
        return formatter
    }

    init() {
        let date = Date()
        var dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: date)
        dateComponents.hour = 20
        dateComponents.minute = 0
        dateComponents.second = 19
        let startDate = Calendar.current.date(from: dateComponents)!
        let newDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 9, to: startDate)!
        var newComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.year, .month, .day, .hour, .minute, .second], from: newDate)
        newComponents.minute = 50
        let endDate = Calendar.current.date(from: newComponents)!
        let dates = (-2...13).map { Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: $0, to: startDate)! }
        self.startDate = startDate
        self.endDate = dates.filter { endDate > $0 }.last!
        self.dates = dates
        data = prices.indices.map { .init(date: dates[$0], cent: prices[$0]) }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Chart(data, id: \.id) { data in
            LineMark(x: .value("Hour", data.date), y: .value("Cent", data.cent))
                .foregroundStyle(.red)
                .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 6))
                .interpolationMethod(.catmullRom)
            if let start = startDate, start == data.date {
                RuleMark(x: .value("Start of charging", start))
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
            if let stop = endDate, stop == data.date {
                RuleMark(x: .value("End of charging", stop))
                    .foregroundStyle(.green)
            }
            if let selectedDate = selectedDate {
                RuleMark(x: .value("Selected date", selectedDate))
                    .annotation(position: .top, alignment: .top) {
                        VStack {
                            Text(dateFromTo(with: selectedDate))
                            Text(centPerkWh(with: selectedCent))
                        }
                        .padding(.bottom, 20)
                    }
                
                if let selectedCent = selectedCent {
                    PointMark(x: .value("Selected date", selectedDate), y: .value("Selected cent", selectedCent))
                        .foregroundStyle(.red)
                        .annotation(position: .overlay, alignment: .center) {
                            Circle()
                                .frame(width: 20, height: 20)
                                .foregroundColor(.red)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .chartYAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .leading)
        }
        .chartXAxis {
            AxisMarks(position: .bottom) {
                AxisGridLine()
                AxisTick()
                if let value = $0.as(Date.self) {
                    AxisValueLabel {
                        Text(hourFormatter.string(from: value))
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .scaledToFit()
        .chartOverlay { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                ZStack(alignment: .top) {
                    Rectangle().fill(.clear).contentShape(Rectangle())
                        .gesture(DragGesture()
                            .onChanged { value in
                                updateSelectedDate(at: value.location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                            }
                        )
                        .onTapGesture { location in
                            updateSelectedDate(at: location, proxy: proxy, geometry: geometry)
                        }
                }
            }
        }
        .chartBackground { proxy in
            GeometryReader { geo in
                if let startDate = startDate, let endDate = endDate, let startPositionX = proxy.position(forX: startDate), let endPositionX = proxy.position(forX: endDate) {
                    let height = geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].height
                    let width = geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].width
                    let _ = print("startDate:", startDate, "endDate:", endDate, "startPositionX:", startPositionX, "xdiff:", endPositionX - startPositionX, "width:", width)
                    Rectangle()
                        .fill(Color.green.opacity(0.06))
                        .position(x: 208, y: height / 2)
                        .frame(width: endPositionX - startPositionX, height: height)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func updateSelectedDate(at location: CGPoint, proxy: ChartProxy, geometry: GeometryProxy) {
        let xPosition = location.x - geometry[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.x
        guard let date: Date = proxy.value(atX: xPosition) else {
            return
        }
        selectedDate = data
            .sorted(by: {
                abs($0.date.timeIntervalSince(date)) < abs($1.date.timeIntervalSince(date))
            })
            .first?.date
        selectedCent = data.first(where: { $0.date == selectedDate })?.cent
    }

    func dateFromTo(with date: Date?) -> String {
        guard let selectedDate = date, let toDate = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .hour, value: 1, to: selectedDate) else { return "" }

        let from = hourMinuteFormatter.string(from: selectedDate)
        let to = hourMinuteFormatter.string(from: toDate)

        return "\(from)-\(to)"
    }

    func centPerkWh(with cent: Double?) -> String {
        guard let selectedCent = cent else { return "" }
        let formatter = NumberFormatter()
        formatter.currencyCode = "NOK"
        formatter.currencySymbol = ""
        formatter.locale = Locale.autoupdatingCurrent
        formatter.numberStyle = .currency
        formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0

        let formattedValue = formatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: selectedCent)) ?? "-"

        return "\(formattedValue) cent"
    }

}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
            .padding()
    }
}

struct EnergyPriceData: Identifiable {
    var id: String { UUID().uuidString }
    let date: Date
    let cent: Double
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found out why setting the `.position(x: startPositionX, y: height / 2)` didn't work. I must also offset the x-position with half the rectangle's width, because SwiftUI will center the rectangle at the position where I want to draw: `.offset(x: (endPositionX - startPositionX) / 2)` In addition, I must adjust the x position with the origin.x of the plotArea, so the new midStartPositionX will be `let midStartPositionX = startPositionX + geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.x`.

So the new .chartBackground will then be:

```swift
.chartBackground { proxy in
        GeometryReader { geo in
            if let startDate = startDate, let endDate = endDate, let startPositionX = proxy.position(forX: startDate), let endPositionX = proxy.position(forX: endDate), let midStartPositionX = startPositionX + geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].origin.x {
                
                let height = geo[proxy.plotAreaFrame].height
                Rectangle()
                    .fill(Color.green.opacity(0.06))
                    .position(x: midStartPositionX, y: height / 2)
                    .offset(x: (endPositionX - startPositionX) / 2)
                    .frame(width: endPositionX - startPositionX, height: height)
            }
        }
}
```